# Where are my Google Listen podcasts

Tags: podcast, google-listen

I sometimes want to export a downloaded podcast to my computer, but I've yet to find the location where **Google Listen** stores them.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It downloads them to your SD card.

I don't use Google Listen but I installed it and downloaded a podcast. It put it in:

```
/sdcard/com.google.android.apps.listen/downloads
```

The name of the file might be something odd so you might need to rename them but that's where they are all located.

Comment: Since it is only my opinion and not part of my answer, I will add it here. I personally use Pocket Casts from Shifty Jelly. It is a paid app but it is worth the small price, IMHO. =)